# LINQ Expression to Select objects by string property with maximum count of objects in its queue property without duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a queue of Record objects as follows:

```
     public class Record
     {
     public string TypeDesc { get; set; }

     public Queue<Total> Totals { get; set; }

     etc.....
     }
```

I'm having trouble writing a LINQ expression to extract a subset that has only one of each TypeDesc but within each TypeDesc the one with the most Total objects in the Totals queue.

I'm not sure it matters but there is only one TypeDesc that has Total objects in the Totals queue property. All others the queue is empty. There are about 8 unique TypeDesc values.

Here's my attempt but the totals property is not available on "s".

var records = Records.Select(c => c.TypeDesc).Where(s => s.Totals.Count).Max().Distinct();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. group the records by their `TypeDesc` property
2. For each group, select the one with the highest `Totals.Count`.

```
records.GroupBy(r => r.TypeDesc)
       .Select(
            g => g.Aggregate((acc, current) => current.Totals.Count > acc.Totals.Count
                                                    ? current
                                                    : acc));
```

For complex queries like these, it's best to break the logic down a bit, to make the code more readable:

```
Func<IEnumerable<Record>, Record> mostTotals =
    group => group.Aggregate(
        (acc, current) => current.Totals.Count > acc.Totals.Count
                              ? current
                              : acc);

var records = records.GroupBy(r => r.TypeDesc)
                     .Select(mostTotals);
```

Step 2 is achieved by using [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx), which iterates through the records in that group, and uses an "accumulator" to keep track of the record with the highest `Totals.Count` at each iteration.

To simplify, the aggregation function is equivalent to this:

```
//for each group
Record acc = null;

foreach(var current in group)
    acc = current.Totals.Count > acc.Totals.Count
          ? current
          : acc;
```